# Delete all rows from table except one with <th> tags

Tags: jquery

If I have table with id="tbl_users" and I have

```
<tr>
   <th>name</th>
   <th>username</th>
   <th>password</th>
</tr>
```

and bellow I append data. How to empty table ( delete all rows with darta) before reloading users, but not to delete row with  ? I use JQuery in project.

Comment: Danka add thead tag before tr th and tbody before tr td, you html will be more correct and then you can enjoy quick selectors Vivek gave you. Otherwise you would need to use Guffa's which will hit your performance because they are less direct.

Answer (score 21):

If you always have the header line first, you can simply skip it:

```
$('#tbl_users tr').slice(1).remove();
```

Otherwise you can use the `has` method:

```
$('#tbl_users tr').has('td').remove();
```

To specifically look for rows that doesn't have a `th` tag, you can use the `filter` method:

```
$('#tbl_users tr').filter(function() {
  return !$(this).has('th');
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 7):

add `tbody` tag in your html and then do this-

```
 $('#tbl_users').find('tbody').remove();
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question :/

Comment: Corrent HTML Table should have thead, tbody and tfooter. Vivek understands correct tables unlike many others. Reason to use correct table format is very this case when something must be removed or appended without many filtering params.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <tbody>

It should be:

     $("#tbl_users").find('tbody').remove();

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table#tbl_users').find('tr:not(:has(th))).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$('#tbl_users td').parent().remove();
```